# Why try/catch block doesn't cover all the runtime exceptions?

Tags: swift

What I try to do is

```
...
let path: URL? = URL(string: "")
    
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: path!)
    }
    catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
...
```

I know that this code won't work, but what I expect is to catch the error in the catch block instead I get a runtime exception and crash.

Comment: Because you're using `path!`, so you're forcing the unwrapping and do/catch blocks are not meant for handling unwrapping.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Swift can you trap "fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805193/in-swift-can-you-trap-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-op)

Comment: Failed force unwraps are ALWAYS a programmer error and therefore need to be prevented by the programmer by writing proper code that does not force unwrap.

Comment: Side note, you said "Run time exception", and a `do`/`try`/`catch` will get only thrown `Error` from method that `throws`, not exception (especially, not `NSException`/`NSUncaughtException`, that you can also find along `Fatal Errors`).

Comment: Others have answered your question regarding the force unwrapping operator. But, do I infer from your choice of `path` for your variable name that you're accessing a file on your local file system? If the string you provide to `URL` initializer is a path, then obviously you would use [`URL(fileURLWithPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126800-init), not `URL(string:)`. The latter is used only when dealing with a proper URL (e.g., a string that begins with a scheme of `https://` or `file://` or whatever). If the string is a path, then use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
..
if let path = URL(string: "someStringForUrl") {
    
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
    }
    catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
}
...
```

Comment: The answer doesn't explain the reason why try/catch can't handle the error thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You never reach the `try`, so you never reach the `catch`. Before any of that can happen, the `path!` forced unwrap fails and crashes the app.

(Crashing the app is a runtime exception, which is a completely different thing from the Swift `try/catch` mechanism. It doesn't not "cover all the runtime exceptions"; it doesn't cover *any* runtime exceptions. You're confusing apples with elephants; they are totally unrelated. Runtime exceptions are not thrown-caught Error objects, and vice versa.)

Comment: Worth noting the lingo for the things that Swift's error handling mechnism throws/catches is called an "error"

Comment: @Alexander It throws an object that conforms to a protocol type called Error, true enough.

Comment: Isn't that the only kind of error (not referring to the `Error` protocol, just error in general) that can be caught by any means? Swift has no other error-handling features for catching Mach exceptions, POSIX signals, ObjC exceptions, etc.

Comment: My point is that they could have called it anything; Error was arguably a poor choice. It's really just a controlled form of jumping, similar to `break` or `return`, along with a payload. A crash is totally different.

Comment: Indeed, what I'm saying is that the naming distinction *exists* in the existing Swift literature, and knowing that's Swift error-handling deals with Error and not traps/exceptions/etc. helps demystify why fatalError, forced-unwrapping, etc. can't be caught with `catch`. That's why I think it's important to explain the terminology.

Comment: I believe the crux of the issue is that developers (me included) come from other languages expecting a try/catch block to handle all sorts of exceptions. Whereas in Swift there's a distinction between errors and exceptions.

Comment: @AndréHerculano Swift errors are basically just a language-internal flow control mechanism, on a par with loops and `break`.